# Definition of the residue of a meromorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading in Gamelin’s Complex Analysis and he defines the residue in the following way.

Suppose $z_0$ is an isolated singularity of $f(z)$ and that $f(z)$ has Laurent series $f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n (z-z_0)^n$

where $0 < |z-z_0| < \rho.$

We define the residue of $f(z)$ at $z_0$ to be the coefficient a_{-1} of $\frac{1}{z-z_0}$ in this Laurent expansion, $$a_{-1} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z-z_0|} f(z)dz,$$ where $r$ is any fixed radius $0 < r < \rho.$

My question is, is it assumed to be only one singularity $z_0$ in the punctured disc $0 < |z-z_0| < \rho$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Since $z_0$ is an isolated singularity we know such $\rho$ exists. The function is holomorphic in some deleted neighborhood of $z_0$.

Comment: Thank you, of course that must be so. In retrospect I don’t think this question adds any value to MSE. Do you think I should delete the thread?

Comment: I don't know, that's your choice. Why do you think that's a bad question?

Comment: This question adds value to MSE. Anyone first learning complex analysis would ask the same question.